# android Get the azimuth of phone when picture was taken

Tags: android

I can use the SensorManager and SensorEventListener to get the azimuth.  I am wondering if the built in Intent to capture an image provides the azimuth or orientation?
Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Not by default... but good idea.

Here's a list of exif tags present on one of the pics from my Moto droid on Android 2.1.

```
File name    : 2009-11-11 17.00.20.jpg
File size    : 1147174 bytes
File date    : 2009:11:11 18:00:20
Camera make  : Motorola
Camera model : Droid
Date/Time    : 2009:11:11 17:00:11
Resolution   : 2592 x 1936
Orientation  : rotate 90
Flash used   : No
Exposure time: 0.100 s  (1/10)
Aperture     : f/2.8
ISO equiv.   : 200
Whitebalance : Auto
Metering Mode: center weight
Exposure     : program (auto)
GPS Latitude : N 44d 55m 44s
GPS Longitude: W 77d 22m 22s
```

I bet there's a way to add it to the image... With the onboard orientation sensor you can calculate azimuth.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the info Brad.